# React Native, <TextInput> onChange{(text) => setState(text)} is returning an object instead of a string. Eventhough the default value is a String. Why

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-redux, textinput

```
<TextInput
  onChange={(text) => {
    setEmail(text);
  }}
  style={styles.textInput}
  placeholder="Email"
/>
<TextInput
  onChange={(text) => setPassword(text)}
  style={styles.textInput}
  secureTextEntry
  placeholder="Password"
/>
```

I am trying to set the email and password states

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("default");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("default");
```

I need to use them to login with firebase auth, but as soon as I enter a value in the field the states change to objects, and the firebase function only accepts String values, I have tried converting the values to String() while using the set methods but it doesn't work.

What could possibly be wrong here?

Screenshots:
Before Values it is String, after entering values they become objects.
[image: type of for both states before value is String][image: after entering values they become objects]

Comment: use OnChangeText, it will return string always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because argument of [onChange](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange) is an `object` & not a `text`.

```
{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }
```

`text` is an `object` not a `string`.

```
onChange={(text) => {
    setEmail(text);
  }}
```

**Solution** is to use the [onChangeText](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) event, which passes the `text` as `string`.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={newText => setEmail(newText)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onChange={(text) => setPassword(text)}
```

change it like this

```
onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
```

text is an event object

live example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hofstadter-eep6d0)